# How to do a nested group by in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to do a group by for a select element with angular js,starting from this json file:

```
 [ { city:'Casacanditella', region: 'Abruzzo' ,
id: 19,name: 'museo prova' },
{ city'Archi', region: 'Abruzzo',
id: 20,name: 'Museo aperto' }]
```

What I want is to have the element displayed in this way

- Region

  - City

    - Name

so grouped by region and then by city. How can i do it ? I've tried to do something like this

```
ng-options="m.museumName group by (m.region and m.city ) for m in museum"
```

It's obviously wrong,but in practice is what I expect to see.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. Im not sure if it is possible to do group by on `select` tag by twice. But I made string manipulation on grouping by.

`ng-options="museum.name group by museum.region + ' ' + museum.city for museum in museums"></select>`

Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LKzF5ixmAJdTsJeaA577?p=preview)

Comment: I've tried in this way too,is a way out but not what I'm looking for but, as you said, maybe it's not possible and I'm looking for Pandora :). Thanks .